# Is it possible to pause an automation using SSJS in SFMC?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ssjs, cloudpage, automation

This code temporarily pauses the automation until the scheduler time is reached. After that it completes the automation and sets scheduler back to 'Active' state. Is it possible to permanently set the scheduler to 'Pause' state using SSJS?:

```javascript
var rr = Platform.Function.CreateObject("RetrieveRequest");
Platform.Function.SetObjectProperty(rr, "ObjectType", "Automation");
Platform.Function.AddObjectArrayItem(rr, "Properties", "Name");
Platform.Function.AddObjectArrayItem(rr, "Properties", "CustomerKey");
Platform.Function.AddObjectArrayItem(rr, "Properties", "ProgramID");
Platform.Function.AddObjectArrayItem(rr, "Properties", "Status");

var sfp = Platform.Function.CreateObject("SimpleFilterPart");
Platform.Function.SetObjectProperty(sfp, "Property", "CustomerKey");
Platform.Function.SetObjectProperty(sfp, "SimpleOperator", "equals");
Platform.Function.AddObjectArrayItem(sfp, "Value", AutomationExternalKey);

Platform.Function.SetObjectProperty(rr, "Filter", sfp);

var StatusAndRequestID = [0,0];
var Result = Platform.Function.InvokeRetrieve(rr,StatusAndRequestID);
var AutomationObjectID = Result[0].ObjectID;
var obj = Platform.Function.CreateObject("Automation");

Platform.Function.SetObjectProperty(obj, "ObjectID", AutomationObjectID);

var po = Platform.Function.CreateObject("PerformOptions");
var performResult = [0,0,0];
var performStatus = Platform.Function.InvokePerform(obj, "stop", performResult, po);
```

Comment: What you're looking for is pauseSchedule. I'm not sure if it's possible using ampscript/ soap but internal rest API seems to have an POST endpoint. The definition ID is the one that you see in URL. 

https://mc.s7.marketingcloudapps.com/AutomationStudioFuel3/fuelapi/legacy/v1/beta/bulk/automations/automation/definition/?action=pauseSchedule

{"id":"Y2VLN2V3RnNOazJrRk9pRmUxZURXZzoyNTow","scheduleObject":{"id":"bFdUTy1Gb21YRXFJT21CbFphaHBxdzozNjow"}}

Try exploring internal API and you might find solution.

Answer (score 0):

Don't have a complete answer, but a functional workaround and some puzzle pieces:

A sample for pausing automations is documented here:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/interacting_with_automation_studio_via_the_web_service_soap_api.html#pause-an-automation

So it is definitely possible via SOAP API, and you can send SOAP API calls from SSJS. See example, you will need the objectId, but you have that one already from your code. You'll also need an API token, but then this is a simple HTTP.POST call using the below payload.

The documentation piece has been adjusted to work with token instead of Username/Password:

`POST {{soapEndpoint}}/Service.asmx`

Headers:

`SOAPAction`: `"Schedule"`

`Content-Type`:`text/xml; charset=UTF-8`

Body:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
   <soap:Header>
        <fueloauth>{{access_token}}</fueloauth>
   </soap:Header>
   <soap:Body>
      <ScheduleRequestMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
         <Action>pause</Action>
         <Schedule>
         </Schedule>
         <Interactions>
            <Interaction xsi:type="Automation">
               <ObjectID>INSERT OBJECT ID</ObjectID>
            </Interaction>
         </Interactions>
      </ScheduleRequestMsg>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

this works in postMan and successfully pauses an automation.

now you can transfer it into an SSJS wrapper:

```
var result = ""

try {
var soapEndpoint = 'https://TENANT.soap.marketingcloudapis.com/Service.asmx';

var accessToken = 'INSERT HERE '
var contentType = 'text/xml; charset=UTF-8';
var headerNames = ["SOAPAction"];
var headerValues = ["Schedule"];
var payload = '<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">'
payload += '    <soap:Header>'
payload += '       <fueloauth>' + accessToken + '</fueloauth>'
payload += '    </soap:Header>'
payload += '    <soap:Body>'
payload += '          <ScheduleRequestMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">'
payload += '             <Action>pause</Action>'
payload += '             <Schedule>'
payload += '             </Schedule>'
payload += '             <Interactions>'
payload += '                <Interaction xsi:type="Automation">'
payload += '                   <ObjectID>' + AutomationObjectID + '</ObjectID>'
payload += '                </Interaction>'
payload += '             </Interactions>'
payload += '          </ScheduleRequestMsg>'
payload += '    </soap:Body>'
payload += '</soap:Envelope>'

var result = HTTP.Post(soapEndpoint,contentType,payload,headerNames,headerValues);
var statusCode = result["StatusCode"];
var scheduleResponse = result["Response"][0];
scheduleResponse = Stringify(scheduleResponse).replace(/[\n\r]/g, '');
Write("scheduleResponse " + scheduleResponse);


} catch(e) {
Write(Stringify(e))
}
```

Response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
    <soap:Header>
        <wsa:Action>ScheduleResponse</wsa:Action>
        <wsa:MessageID>urn:uuid:d3a7183a-04d1-4871-a5a9-b0861805f020</wsa:MessageID>
        <wsa:RelatesTo>urn:uuid:9bf18bde-aefa-4b03-a274-18a08e99f7cf</wsa:RelatesTo>
        <wsa:To>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/role/anonymous</wsa:To>
        <wsse:Security>
            <wsu:Timestamp wsu:Id="Timestamp-8ec75dbd-57d4-48ce-b686-0bc6b4e1ddf7">
                <wsu:Created>2021-11-22T19:26:59Z</wsu:Created>
                <wsu:Expires>2021-11-22T19:31:59Z</wsu:Expires>
            </wsu:Timestamp>
        </wsse:Security>
    </soap:Header>
    <soap:Body>
        <ScheduleResponseMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
            <Results>
                <Result>
                    <StatusCode>OK</StatusCode>
                    <StatusMessage>Schedule Paused. To reactivate the schedule use proxy.Schedule with the action 'start'.</StatusMessage>
                    <Object>
                        <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true" />
                        <ObjectID xsi:nil="true" />
                    </Object>
                    <Task />
                </Result>
            </Results>
            <OverallStatus>OK</OverallStatus>
            <OverallStatusMessage />
            <RequestID>aa3dfde2-8a01-44d6-99d4-c8c1678dbfb2</RequestID>
        </ScheduleResponseMsg>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Going that route is probably way faster than finding the way to mimick that Soap Call via the Object creation SSJS syntax.

====

From here onwards, this is more of a material collection, not a solution.

Maybe someone else can help with not getting a token and using the API but constructing this similarly to the retrieveRequest you already have inside plain SSJS (`CreateObject` etc).

I just tried and failed (which is a pretty common pattern with this syntax and myself), but I found some fragments, maybe it is a start:

The api payload above clearly mimicks this method:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/schedule.html

which I am unable to reconstruct using the SSJS syntax, but it should be feasible if you manage to wrap your head around the logic.

If you manage to invoke this method, you probably need an "interactionBaseObject" in which the objectId resides.

```
var interactions = Platform.Function.CreateObject("InteractionBaseObject");
Platform.Function.SetObjectProperty(interactions, "ObjectID",AutomationObjectID);
```

my guess is that invoking would work using "invokeSchedule":
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/ssjs_platformAPIInvokeSchedule.htm

which is only documented in C# like this:

```
ScheduleResult[] schedule = Schedule(Options, Action, Schedule1, Interactions, OverallStatus, OverallStatusMessage, RequestID)
```